# On-Screen Keyboard in Kubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, kubuntu

I have a HP Envy x2 15-c000ng Notebook/Tablet Hybrid running Kubuntu 16.04 LTS with KDE Plasma 5.6.5, KDE Frameworks 5.23.0, Qt 5.5.1, Kernel 4.4.0-38-generic, 64-bit.

So far I found no built-in on-screen keyboard and also none that can be installed on 16.04. In Ubuntu and Ubuntu GNOME there are built-in keyboards that are found via the accessibility functions. Did I miss something in Kubuntu?

Any help is appreciated. Kind regards,

Alex

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no default on-screen keyboard available in Kubuntu. I had the very same issue in Kubuntu 17.04. I tried to install different virtual keyboards but none of them is better than Onboard (Onboard on-screen keyboard).
You can try to install it from Discover app or simply just by typing`sudo apt install onboard` in konsole terminal emulator.
If you are intrested to search for other virtual keyboards you can find them in Ubuntu Software or Discover app by searching for onscreen keyboard or virtual keyboard or just type in terminal:

```
apt search virtual keyboard
```

or

```
apt search onscreen keyboard
```